# Razor templating with SiteEdit UI 2012 onTridion 2011

Tags: razor, tridion, tridion-2011, siteedit

This is regarding Razor Templating with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

To enable SiteEdit UI 2012, we are introducing  tags within CTs.

I would like to ask if it is possible to make `tcdl:ComponentField` tag for the field residing inside nested Embedded Field of a Component.

Here we have Component with "footer_links" as Multivalued Embedded Field and again each "footer_links" item has a Multivalued Embedded Field "sub_nav"
and want to read sub_nav.image to make it suite editable.

But when I do following, enable inline editing for content TBB throws following error

> Error :
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating.EnableInlineEditingUI.FindItemFieldXPath(String[] parts, Int32 currentIndex, ItemFields fields)

Anyone has any idea? If we can implement this? If yes, then whats wrong with following code?

Also can we read the Fields inside ComponentLink for same?
Help would be appreciated.

```
@for (int i=0; i<Fields.footer_links.Count; i++) {
/* "outer_image" is compLink and it workds fine */
   @if(Fields.footer_links[i].outer_image != null) {
   <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[@i].outer_image">
    <img src="@Fields.footer_links[i].outer_image.ID"/>
  </tcdl:ComponentField>              
  }

  /* "sub_nav" is Mutlivalued Embedded field and "image" is field inside it */

   @for (int j=0; j<Fields.footer_links[i].sub_nav.Count; j++) {
   <li>
   @if(Fields.footer_links[i].sub_nav[j].image != null) {
   <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[@i].sub_nav[@j].image">
      <img src="@Fields.footer_links[i].sub_nav[j].image.ID" />
    </tcdl:ComponentField>
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you tried like this way

```
    @foreach(dynamic com in Fields.footer_links) {
/* "outer_image" is compLink and it workds fine */
   @if(com.outer_image != null) {
   <tcdl:ComponentField name="com.Fields.outer_image">
    <img src="@com.Fields.outer_image.ID"/>
  </tcdl:ComponentField>              
  }

  /* "sub_nav" is Mutlivalued Embedded field and "image" is field inside it */

   @foreach (dynamic subCom in com.sub_nav) {
   <li>
   @if(subCom.image != null) {
   <tcdl:ComponentField name="subCom.Fields.image">
      <img src="@subCom.Fields.image.ID" />
    </tcdl:ComponentField>
   }
}
}
```

Because, it seems the below line @i does not convert the value like in Int type

```
 <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[@i].outer_image">
```

Comment: This isn't working, with line of code '<tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[@i].outer_image">' its getting resolved nicely but problem is later case  ie '<tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[@i].sub_nav[@j].image">' even in this case in the output when i check i see <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[0].sub_nav[0].image">  <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[0].sub_nav[1].image"><tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[0].sub_nav[2].image"> <tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.footer_links[1].sub_nav[0].image"> and so on.. but still error persists

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have trouble generating the tcdl tag?

To solve this you can create a helper method that generates the tag for you:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString SiteEditComponentField(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
```

In this extension method you can easily return a formatted string with the tag and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Its a long time so not sure what you are using but you can certainly use razor mediator inbuilt function for same similar to dwt

```
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex)
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, bool renderTcdlTagOnError)
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, string value)
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, string value, bool renderTcdlTagOnError)
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, bool htmlEncodeResult, bool resolveHtmlAsRTFContent)
String RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, bool htmlEncodeResult, bool resolveHtmlAsRTFContent, renderTcdlTagOnError)
```

Thanks..